# Code for Using StAX in java

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have an 200 MB xml of the following form:

```
      <school name = "some school">
        <class standard = "2A">
           <student>  
             ..... 
           </student>
           <student>  
             ..... 
           </student>
           <student>  
             ..... 
           </student>
         </class>
       </school>
```

I need to **split this xml into several files** using StAX such **that n students come under each xml file** and the structure is preserved as `<school>` then `<class>` and `<students>` under them. The attributes of School and class also must be preserved in the resultant xmls.

Here is the code I am using:

```
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

    String xmlFile = "input.XML";
    XMLEventReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileReader(xmlFile));

    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    outputFactory.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isRepairingNamespaces", Boolean.TRUE);

    XMLEventWriter writer = null;

    int count = 0;

    QName name = new QName(null, "student");

    try {
        while (true) {
            XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                StartElement element = event.asStartElement();
                if (element.getName().equals(name)) {
                    String filename = "input"+ count + ".xml";
                    writer = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
                    writeToFile(reader, event, writer);
                    writer.close();
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (event.isEndDocument())
                break;
        }
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

private static void writeToFile(XMLEventReader reader, XMLEvent startEvent, XMLEventWriter writer) throws XMLStreamException, IOException {

    StartElement element = startEvent.asStartElement();
    QName name = element.getName();
    int stack = 1;

    writer.add(element);

    while (true) {
        XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
        if (event.isStartElement() && event.asStartElement().getName().equals(name))
            stack++;
        if (event.isEndElement()) {
            EndElement end = event.asEndElement();
            if (end.getName().equals(name)) {
                stack--;
                if (stack == 0) {
                    writer.add(event);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        writer.add(event);
    }

}
```

Please check the function call `writeToFile(reader, event, writer)` in the try block. Here the reader object has only the `student` tag. I need the reader has the `school`, `class`, and then n `students` in it. so that the file generated has a similar structure as the original only with lesser children per file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a code-generation service. Try it yourself (using the samples you found) and post a **concrete** question when you run into a problem.

Comment: then **post** what you attempted and **explain** where you are stuck. I **do** want to help, but I don't want to be a code-generation service (and I don't want this site to become one).

Comment: Please refrain from reprimanding users with about 260 times your reputation.

Comment: I think u may want to consider using vtd-xml to do it, not only will it be faster, but also much easier (u can use xpath)

Answer (score 0):

You have code for determining when to start a new file which I haven't examined closely, but the process of finishing one file and starting the next is definitely incomplete.

On reaching a point where you want to end a file, you have to generate end events for the enclosing `<class>` and `<school>` tags and for the document before closing it.  When you start your new file, you need to generate start events for the same after opening it and before starting again to copy student events.

In order to generate the start events properly, you will have to retain the corresponding events from the input.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself trouble and time and use the flat xml file structure you currently have, and then create POJO Objects which will represent each object as you've stated; **Student**, **School** and **Class**. And then using Jaxb bind the objects with different part of the Structure. You can then effectively unmarshal the xml and access the various elements as if you're dealing with SQL objects.

Use this link as a starting point [XML parsing with JAXB](http://wiki.processing.org/w/XML_parsing_with_JAXB)

One issue doing it this way is memory consumption. For design flexibility and memory management, I will suggest using SQL to handle this.

Comment: The problem is the XML is 200MB, may run out of memory if using JAXB to parse the entire XML into an object tree.

Comment: @Alvin 200mb is quiet a big file - but i think going through design approach of spliting the root file is not going to solve his problem of memory management and even flexibility. What if the Student file grows to 200Mb?! then another routine to split that down?!

Comment: my issue is exactly what u suspect. If any file grows more than a certain size, it will be broken down again.

Comment: But right now my only concern is to break the files with only the children being distributed and the hierarchy preserved.

Comment: @Anand In that case I will point you back to Don Roby's Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep track of list of parent events prior to the "student" start element event and pass it to the writeToFile() method. Then in the writeToFile() method you can use that list to simulate the "school" and "class" events.